# Using VBA in Excel to share cell vales between sheets to populate data in cells

Tags: excel, vba

**Updated Question**

I have a VBA script attached to sheet 1 that uses the B5:B50 cell values to populate the adjacent column with pre-defined text. If I want to use this script in another sheet, but still use the B5:B50 cell values of the previous sheet. How to I do that?

For Example:

In sheet 1, If I enter the value of 2 in the cell B5, it will populate D5 and E5 with the text value attached to CONST TXT. I want to do the same thing in sheet 2, but instead of the user entering the value again into B5 of sheet 2, it just gets the value of B5 from the previous sheet and then populate D5 and E5.

Sheet 2 B values will need to update as soon as the B values are updated in Sheet 1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const NUM_COLS As Long = 5
    Const TXT = "• Course Name:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. Of Slides Affected:" & vbNewLine & _
              "• No. of Activities Affected:"

    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, v

    If Target.CountLarge <> 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B5:B50")) Is Nothing Then

        Set rng = Target.Offset(0, 2).Resize(1, NUM_COLS) 'range to check
        v = Target.Value

        If IsNumeric(v) And v >= 1 And v <= NUM_COLS Then
            For i = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
                With rng.Cells(i)
                    If i <= v Then
                        'Populate if not already populated
                        If .Value = "" Then .Value = TXT
                    Else
                        'Clear any existing value
                        .Value = ""
                    End If
                End With
            Next i
        Else
            rng.Value = "" 'clear any existing content
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Updated Question to better clarify the issue i'm facing

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you want something like an equivalent of `offset` which returns a range on a different sheet.  There are a couple of options.

You can use `Range.AddressLocal`, which returns the address of `Range` without any worksheet or workbook qualifiers, and then apply this to the other worksheet:

```vb
'returns a cell 1 to the right of rng, but on Sheet2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(rng.Offset(0, 1).AddressLocal)
```

Or you can get the `Row` and `Column` properties of your range and use them in `Cells` in the other worksheet:

```vb
'returns a cell 1 to the right of rng, but on Sheet2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column + 1)
```

To use it in your code, I think it's just a case of replacing

```vb
If .Value = "" Then .Value = TXT
```

with

```vb
If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(.Offset(0, 1).AddressLocal).Value = "" Then Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(.Offset(0, 1).AddressLocal).Value = TXT
```

and replacing

```vb
.Value = ""
```

with

```vb
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(.Offset(0, 1).AddressLocal).Value = ""
```

(or the same using the `Cells` construction).

Comment: Sheet 1 is currently using the script above. So when i enter a value into B5:B50, it populates cells in the same row with a pre-defined text. What im looking to do is, when B5:B50 is populated in Sheet 1, it populates cells in the same row with pre-defined text but in sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

The below will copy the `Target.Value` into the same cell in `Sheet2`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B5:B50")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        With Target
            ws2.Cells(.Row, .Column).Value = .Value
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```